# Android Services

Tags: java, android, sockets, webserver, android-service

I'm writing a web server for android. Actually it works with threads, but now I would use a service to make it running in background. I replaced the thread with a service, but I don't know if this design is ok...
When I press a button it starts then it stays in listening. When there is a request, the service create a thread to serve it.
This is my structure:

**WebServer.java**

```
class WebServer extends Service{
 onCreate(){...}
 onDestroy(){...}
}
```

**DroidServer.java**

```
class DroidServer extends WebServer{...}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
MyActivity extends Activity{
boolean isOn=false;
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(View V){
  if(!isOn){
   startService(new Intent(this, DroidWebServer.class));
   btn.setText("Stop");
  }else{
   stopService(new Intent(this, DroidWebServer.class));
   btn.setText("Start");
    }}});
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
... <service android:name='DroidWebServer'/> ...
```

But when I click on the button I get this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to Instantiate service it.giox.ws.DroidWebServer: java.lang.InstantiationException: it.giox.ws.DroidWebServer
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1933)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: it.giox.ws.DroidWebServer
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1930)
    ... 10 more
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/07f95399771fa3a0) post? It basically says there is an error in your constructor. His fix was to remove the argument, and also make sure to call the super's constructor ...

> InstantiationException occurs when an exception is thrown out of a 
>   constructor.  Generally there should be another exception reported as 
>   causing the InstantiationException, and the stack trace should point 
>   to the specific lines that are in error.  Stack trace is your friend, 
>   and you should be grateful -- their are poor children programming on 
>   Symbian devices who have no stack trace.

Comment: My problem is that I should extend both service and webserver, but since it's impossible I want to know if my solution is conceptually right. I saw that post, but it seems different from my design.. And, in my case I've to pass parameters to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the callback method onStartCommand() in your subclass (either WerServer or DroidServer)? Check out [Service.startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) for details.

Personally, I think use the bound form of service is more reasonable in your design, where you can replace a is-a relationship with a has-a relationship.

Your WebServer:

```
class WebServer implements IWebServer {
  doSoming();
}
```

Your DroidServer:

```
class DroidServer extends Service {
  private WebServer webServer;
  private WebServerBinder myBinder;

  onCreate(){...}

  IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myBinder;
  }

  onDestroy(){...}

  protected class WebServerBinder extends Binder implements IWebServer {
    doSomething() {
      myServer.doSomething();
    }
  }
```

}

In your Activity, use your DroidServer like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private IWebServer myWebService;

  private ServiceConnection myServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
      myWebService = (IWebServer) service;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
      if (myWebService != null)
        myWebService = null;
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bindService(new Intent(this, DroidWebServer.class),
      myServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    boolean isOn=false;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View V){
        if(!isOn){
          myWebService.doSomething();
          btn.setText("Stop");
        }else{
          myWebService.doSomethingElse(someParam);
          btn.setText("Start");
        }}});
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(myServiceConnection );
  }
}
```